# Use Case diagram?

Tags: uml, use-case

I am studying UML after a long long time so having difficulty in getting it. Somewhere I am hanging between either I should draw a generalized diagram or specific one and what if generalization of actors is required. I will appreciate if you ppl pull me out of this fuss with a perfect diagram for the following scenario.

Suppose you are going to develop a library information system.
Create a use case diagram to show the following requirements.

(a) All the registered users, including the borrowers and the librarians, can login to the system, browse titles and search for desired titles.

(b) A borrower can check out and return items. She can also reserve a title that is not currently available in the library. The reservation is automatically removed when the borrower checks out a copy (an item) of that title, or through an explicit cancelling procedure.

(c) A librarian has management capability to add borrowers, titles, and items. Occasionally a librarian herself can be a borrower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use case Diagram shows the relationship between functionalities and their performer i.e actor and use case(functionality).

Actor shows like human and use case title of functionalty in oval shape.

As per your description

(a) You have Registered User is an actor  and Login is functionality. User will have different types, in that case you can use inheritance(generalisation)  relationship.
(b) Borrower is an actor. check out Item, return items, and  reserve Item and cancel reservation are the functionalities(use cases) Borrow functionality <> reservation list which is also affected by reservation and cancellation functionality. So You have **change reservation list** which will be used by Borrow item, reservation and cancellation.
(c) These librarian is user(Actor defined in(a)). User can borrow the title. Now attach following functionalities(use cases)  add borrower, add title and add item to librarian.

Here you will get more idea

[Library Management system UML](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue67/gilliam.html)

Comment: Thanks for the details you mentioned. I have a better idea towards the diagram now. One thing that mess me up is Librarian got the same functions as a user and then all the functionalities mentioned have been said to belong to a registered user.

Comment: The functionalities or use cases that are similar for both actors i.e login to the system, search titles infact in the last part, it is mentioned that a librarian can be herself a borrower so there would be different clouds for each functionality  for two actors or they will share the same.

Comment: @Alex There are two approaches if two different actors uses the same functionality(usecase) 1. you will have same functionality but map to both I mean you have one cloud for the librarian and registered user and link to both the user. 2. Another approach is, have User which extended by Registered and Librarian. User will map to common functionality

Comment: Well that makes a sense now. I will concentrate. Many thanks for the help